# python script to match C function signature in multiple lines

Tags: python

I am reading .c file to look out for functions defined in it and count number of lines in each function. 
My problem is that I am unable to look for function name/signature spanned across multiple ines. 
I have the list of function names of .c file and i am matching the function names of this list with functions in .c file to process further.

e.g. My .c file is:

```
 1.   int main(
 2.           void
 3.          )
```

here main signature is spanned over three lines.

and I have a list of functions as:

```
 int main(void);
```

how can i match "int main(void)" with multiline main in .c file ?
I want to start counting lines once function is matched.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write a simple parser for the C language.

One of the examples in the [ANTLR book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference) does something similar to what you're after.

[Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) is a very nice Python library for writing parsers.

Here is a parser for ANSI C: http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/ (written using another Python parser library, [Ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)).

Answer (score 0):

If you have definition that matches "exactly" then you can use regex:

```
int\s+main\s*\(\s*void\s*\)\s*;
```

where \s* means zero or more whitechars, and \s+ one or more whitechars.

To use it with multiline search you can define it like:

```
RE_MAIN = re.compile(r'int\s+main\s*\(\s*void\s*\)\s*;', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

By "exactly" I mean that it does not match function definition like

```
int main();
```

(void omitted)

This way you can find where the function begins, then do simple char scanner counting { and } remembering to ignore comments and ignore chars and strings constants